# Usage of Spring Security in a Maven App

Tags: java, spring, maven

I would like to get some indications and explanations while never forget that I am a J2E total newbie.

I built a new WebApp using the archetype Sample-WebApp of Maven, and using Spring 4, Hibernate 4, JSF 2, PrimeFaces 5, MySQL 5 and Eclipse Mars.

I was getting into a tutorial about how to read a username and test existence from a database (that's how any language education starts for me) and then found that some are using Spring Security. My Initial idea was to test a foreign key UserType, and if it's value is 1, we get to a superadmin fodler, otherwise, it takes us to normal welcome folder depending on other types (2=Instructor, 3=Student ...), while doing that I found that some tutorials are using somekinf of a Spring Security that does this, and would like to know how It is used in this kind of app built based on http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/jsf-2-primefaces-3-spring-3-hibernate-4.html Tutorial, and if my initial method is better than using this or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://marco-ng.blogspot.com/2014/02/primefaces-jsf2-spring-security-spring.html

Is the right solution + mvn update-versions in the POM :)

Thank you for your help ()